# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

> Неделю спустя моего возвращения в замок(,) стражники передали весть о...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В интересующем Вас предложении налицо пропуск предлога *после* перед словами *моего возвращения*.

«Обстоятельства, выраженные именами существительными, без предлогов или с иными предлогами, обособляются только в том случае, если приобретают дополнительную смысловую нагрузку, имеют пояснительное значение или совмещают несколько обстоятельственных значений (временное и причинное, временное и уступительное и др.).

Например: *Петя, **после полученного им решительного отказа**, ушёл в свою комнату* (Л. Толстой).

В данном случае обстоятельство совмещает значения времени и причины (*когда ушёл?* и *почему ушёл?*). Обратите внимание на то, что оборот выражен существительным с зависимыми словами и расположен между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Обособленные обстоятельства, выраженные существительными, всегда выделяются интонационно. Однако наличие паузы не всегда свидетельствует о наличии запятой. Так, всегда интонационно выделяются обстоятельства, которые стоят в начале предложения.

Ср.: *В Петербурге / я был в прошлом году; В прошлом году / я был в Петербурге.*

Однако запятая после такого обстоятельства не ставится!» (Балашова Л. В., Дементьев В. В. «Курс русского языка»).

Не обойдем молчанием и таком феномен, как авторская пунктуация. 
Законность расширения функций того или иного пунктуационного знака, а также отступления от действующих норм пунктуации, дает автору право членить текст с помощью пунктуационных знаков таким образом, какой он полагает наиболее полно раскрывающим его, авторский, замысел. Литераторы как периода расцвета русской литературы, так и периода ее упадка активно пользовались этим правом, и никто из них не был заклеймен позором под крики «Неуч!». И надо сказать, не было причин клеймить. Ведь их пунктуационные решения не препятствуют верному истолкованию написанного. Что из этого следует, господа?

Comment: 1. Сами по себе художественные тексты доказательством служить не могут, но это интересный материал для работы. Учебные примеры, которые придумываются для иллюстрации правил, нельзя считать живой русской речью. Кроме того, тексты проверяются корректорами и редакторами, так что определенное доверие к ним есть.

Comment: 2. С интонацией все немного сложнее, чем вы излагаете. У интонации две основные составляющие - паузы различной длительности и тоническое ударение. Распространенный детерминант в начале фразы иногда может отделяться небольшой паузой, но при этом не имеет тонического ударения (это деление фразы на произносительные синтагмы), и в этом случае запятая не ставится. Запятыми разделяют фразы - отрезки речи с тоническим ударением. В нашем примере распространенный оборот вполне претендует на такую отдельную фразу.

Comment: 1. Корректоры и редакторы? Я Вас умоляю... Этим корректорам уже Розенталя взять в руки в службу. Они сидят в ЖЖ и спрашивают у всех, кому не лень отвечать, может ли автор ставить тире, где ему вздумается, или не может. Найти сейчас книгу, где не найти ошибок, не легче, чем найти цивилизацию на Марсе. Вот так сейчас работают достопочтеннейшие корректоры и редакторы, как, впрочем, и все в этой стране.

Comment: 2. Спасибо за объяснение на профессиональном уровне, но судить о том, насколько соответствуют действительности мои изложения, я не в состоянии, так как профессиональный уровень мне недоступен, — я в состоянии лишь цитировать то, что излагается профессионалами.

Answer (score 2):

София источников не предоставляет, она сама источник... А цитаты из худ. литературы ни в коем случае не доказательство.

Никаких оснований для запятой здесь нет, согласен с Noir.

Comment: Перед вами два предложения: "Благодаря отцу, я и сестры знаем французский, немецкий и английский языки". "Благодаря дождям посевы зазеленели." Что нужно объяснять: почему поставлена запятая или почему не поставлена запятая?

Comment: Естественно, почему поставлена. Благодаря - почти обыкновенный предлог.
Сравните:
1. Из-за отца ни я, ни сестры не знаем ни французского, ни немецкого.
2. Благодаря отцу знаю иностранные языки.

Comment: БЛАГОДАРЯ - это не обыкновенный предлог. Во всех школьных учебниках вы найдете ему тему обособленных обстоятельств с предлогами БЛАГОДАРЯ, ВВИДУ, ВОПРЕКИ и др. Они обособляются факультативно в зависимости от "распространенности, смысловой нагрузки, положения в предложении". Им не требуется, как сказано В ПРИНЯТОМ ОТВЕТЕ, несколько обстоятельственных значений. Обособление для них - это, скорее, норма, поэтому обычно объясняют, почему не обособляется.

Comment: Так что ваш ответ не принят.  Попробуйте еще раз. Вот вы сделали подстановку: вместо предлога БЛАГОДАРЯ использовали предлог ИЗ-ЗА. Я не считаю проверку подстановкой хорошим методом, так как при этом меняется структура предложения. А вопрос такой: чем, с вашей точки зрения, подстановка отличается от подставки?

Comment: Между прочим, в вашем "Благодаря отцу(,) я и сестры..." обособление как минимум факультативно. Как максимум - ошибочно. Если, конечно, не привлекать "параллельных интонаций", "тонических ударений" и пр.

Comment: Уважаемый Niemand, я Вам как-то уже говорила, что в подобных (спорных)случаях я не пользуюсь своими примерами. Это предложение взято из Правил Лопатина, а он цитирует А.П. Чехова. Как вам такой источник? Также могу Вам посоветовать как можно скорее приступить к изучению тонических ударений - это верный способ научиться разбираться в парных вариантах обособленных и необособленных членов.

Comment: Что, правила Лопатина уже приняты к исполнению? Вот не знал )))))))))))))) Это тот самый Лопатин, который предлагал писать "огурци"? Впрочем, тут я не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант: "Неделю спустя моего возвращения в замок, стражники передали весть о...".

Сравнить: Неделю спустя после его первого визита к Мадлен, Савин был здоров и влюблен.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
Обособление подобных обстоятельств факультативно и зависит от различных факторов: распространенности, позиции в предложении, также от наличия уточняющего значения.

ПРИМЕРЫ

"Каков бы хорош жених невесте ни казался, но неделю спустя после свадьбы наверное всякий мужчина в глазах ее будет казаться приятнее мужа" (И. Крылов).

"Она была арестована неделю спустя после дела на Екатерининском канале, потому что ни за что не хотела покинуть столицу".

"Тут осенью, неделю спустя после Покрова, приехал к Петровне пристав, описал все".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

И то правда, надоело мне быть источником, надо воспользоваться чужими трудами, академическими например. Вот Лопатин предполагает, что обстоятельственные члены предложения, имеющие в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания,  очень часто обособляются, но не всегда. Развивая далее свою мысль, он говорит:

«Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ОБОСОБЛЯЮТСЯ, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты МОГУТ НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯТЬСЯ (без необходимости подчеркивания). Спустя несколько времени пришел Весовщиков (М. Г.). — Пришел, спустя несколько времени, Весовщиков».

Обратите внимание: могут не обособляться, хотя обычно обособляются. В нашем случае оборот распространен в большей степени, также  неизвестен объем всего предложения. Для  таких оборотов такие факторы могут стать решающими. При заданном объеме оборота обособление еще факультативно, но добавьте еще пару слов, и оно станет обязательным. Также обособлению способствует препозиция обстоятельства.

Comment: Розенталь: "В зависимости от степени распространенности оборота, степени смысловой его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, стилистических задач и т. д., МОГУТ ОБОСОБЛЯТЬСЯ обстоятельства, выраженные именами существительными с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями". Базовый вариант как раз необособление.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в предложении не нужна.